# Replaced a RAID controller, now Red Hat won't start

Tags: linux, raid, redhat, hardware-raid

I'm working with a client's HP ProLiant ML110 G7.  At the beginning of the week, it wouldn't boot or POST at all.  Over the course of the week, we've replaced the memory, motherboard, and power supply.  It was running two 72 GB SAS drives connected to a HP SmartArray P410 RAID controller with a 256MB memory module.  When the controller was connected to the new motherboard, the computer still wouldn't boot, so we ordered a replacement.  It arrived today, but appears to be DOA because the motherboard won't detect it at all.  The client was getting antsy about downtime, so I grabbed an LSI RAID controller from an old server, installed it, and was pleased to see the Red Hat boot screen after a reboot.  However, I'm greeted with this screen when it's trying to boot:

```
Warning: pci_mmcfg_init marking 256MB space uncacheable.
Red Hat nash version 5.1.19.6 starting
Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
No volume groups found
Volume group "VolGroup00" not found
Unable to access resume device (/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01)
mount: could not find filesystem '/dev/root'
setuproot: moving /dev failed: no such file or directory
setuproot: error mounting /proc: No such file or directory
setuproot: error mounting /sys: No such file or directory
switchroot: mount failed: No such file or directory
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!

Kernel alive
kernel direct mapping tables up to 20bfff000 @ 10000-1a000
```

I'm assuming that the RAID controller is seeing the drives correctly because it's trying to boot into Red Hat, but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: It appears your current initramfs/initrd image in /boot is having trouble with your LSI controller.  This is NOT a catastrophic problem.  You can either pursue another HPE controller, boot from a RH DVD and rebuild the initfs (here's a decent link to start with https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CreateNewInitrd), or reach out to RH for assistance with rebuilding it (your client should be paying support, might as well use it). Assuming these drives are RAID-1, you might consider disconnecting one as a backup in case things go sideways.

Comment: Also be aware that if you stick with LSI, you may encounter issues remirroring your disks.  I do not know for sure.  Unfortunately, I don't have time (Orthodox Easter today where I'm at) to watch this issue and offer further assistance. Hopefully some others can jump in if you have further questions.

Comment: I don't think that they are paying for support - I'll take a look at that link and see what I can do.  Thank you for your help!